# Colorama cursor reset or cls alternative

Tags: python, windows, powershell, cmd, escaping

I have a script that runs on windows 7, for a longer period of time(a few minutes). I would like to use a progress bar along with some other information on a couple more lines(meaning `\r` is no use here since i need multiple lines). I wrote a generator that should wrap an iterable and at every call "resets" the cursor position to the upper left corner of the console to the progress bar and information can be rewritten.

```
import colorama

def progress_bar(iterable: typing.Iterable, length: int = 100):
        """ Takes an iterable and acts as a generator that prints a progress barr each time it yields.

        Splits the iterable and uses one of the copies to get the length of the iterable(consuming the copy in the
        process) before using the second to iterate trough the items, clearing the screen each time and reprinting the
        progress bar before yielding a new item.

        Intended use is as a wrapper for any iterable that is desired to have a progress bar when being iterated over.

        Args:
                 iterable (typing.Iterable):    The iterable to wrap.
                 length   (int, optional):      The length of the desired progress bar.

        Yields:
                 object:                        Elements from the iterable.
        """
        iterable, counter = itertools.tee(iter(iterable), 2)
        total = sum(1 for _ in counter)
        for cur, item in enumerate(iterable):
                print(f'\033[0;0H'
                      f'\n|{"█" * (length * (cur+1)//total)}{" " * (length - (length * (cur+1)//total))}|'
                      f' {100 * (cur+1)//total:3}%\n')
                yield item
```

The cheapest choice is to use os.system('cls') to just flush the entire console, but that is rather(very) slow, adding another 40-50% to the running time of the script(compared to using `colorama` or just printing over and over).

On alternative consoles like ConEmu the `colorama` approach works wonders but the script needs to be packaged and ran on multiple machines so the output needs to be readable on a console that runs on windows 7.

The problem appears when I try to use colorama on win7 `cmd` or `PowerShell`,
 both behave in the same way, they don't really recognize the escape sequence and I get output like:

```
←[0;0H
|█████████                                   |   9%

←[0;0H
|█████████                                   |   9%

←[0;0H
|█████████                                   |   9%

←[0;0H
|█████████                                   |   9%

←[0;0H
|██████████                                  |  10%

←[0;0H
|██████████                                  |  10%
```

Same happens if I use `\033[0;0H`, `\033[1;1H` or `\033[H`.

I read that I somehow need to enable `ansi.sys`(or something of that sort) but I can't find anything further on that.

My question is...

1. How exactly do I make this work?
2. Is there some way to make `colorama` work?(to enable `ansi.sys` trough code maybe?)
3. Is there another way to "reset"(like another library) the cursor to the top left that not as slow as `cls`?

Other libraries(like Click or Clint) are an option since the project is going to be frozen trough `pyinstaller` before being distributed so any dependencies are automatically included(ind if they are not they can be explicitly included).

Comment: python.exe uses the Windows console. CMD and PowerShell are irrelevant here. Prior to Windows 10, the console only directly supports a [C API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions). colorama and ANSICON (not MS-DOS ansi.sys) use and/or hook this API to support virtual terminal sequences.

Comment: I see, so basically Windows API is the answer? If so then how can I interface that with python? Is the a library or module for that?

Comment: [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) should do this for you. Of course, you first need to call `colorama.init()`. Then also change your positioning to 1-based coordinates (e.g. `"\x1b[1;1H"`). Most terminal emulators are forgiving enough to treat 0 as 1 (including the Windows 10 console), but colorama's wrapper for WinAPI `SetConsoleCursorPosition` strictly requires 1-based coordinates.

Comment: You may also want to clear the screen first via `"\x1b[2J"`, but colorama's implementation of this isn't graceful. It clears the entire screen buffer (i.e. all of your scrollback history), like CMD's `cls` command. The built-in [virtual terminal support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) in Windows 10 tries to avoid erasing the screen buffer if possible by adjusting the window and cursor position.